# Play 2.3 implicit json conversion causes null pointer exception

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm trying to parse json into my case class `DealFormMap`

```
case class DealFormMap(limit: Option[Int], filter: Option[DealFormFilterMap])
case class DealFormFilterMap(date: Option[String], code: Option[String])

implicit val dealFormMapReads: Reads[DealFormMap] = (
    (JsPath \ "limit").readNullable[Int] and
    (JsPath \ "filter").readNullable[DealFormFilterMap]
)(DealFormMap)

implicit val dealFormFilterMapReads: Reads[DealFormFilterMap] = (
    (JsPath \ "date").readNullable[String] and
    (JsPath \ "code").readNullable[String]
)(DealFormFilterMap)
```

JSON in question and parsing attempt

```
val str = """{"limit":10,"filter":{"date":"2014-10-27"}}"""
val frm = Json.parse(str).as[DealFormMap]
```

causes a cryptic error stack that I just can't seem to crack

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[NullPointerException: null]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[play_2.11-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [play_2.11-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$14$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:205) [play_2.11-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$14$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:202) [play_2.11-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36) [scala-library-2.11.2.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at play.api.libs.json.PathReads$$anonfun$nullable$1$$anonfun$apply$7$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(JsConstraints.scala:65) ~[play-json_2.11-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at play.api.libs.json.PathReads$$anonfun$nullable$1$$anonfun$apply$7$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(JsConstraints.scala:63) ~[play-json_2.11-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at play.api.libs.json.JsResult$class.fold(JsResult.scala:76) ~[play-json_2.11-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at play.api.libs.json.JsSuccess.fold(JsResult.scala:9) ~[play-json_2.11-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at play.api.libs.json.PathReads$$anonfun$nullable$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(JsConstraints.scala:61) ~[play-json_2.11-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
```

I'm running out of ideas here, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The problem is the initialization order. `dealFormMapReads` depends on the implicit `dealFormFilterMapReads`, which isn't defined until after. It will compile because the implicit is found, even though it hasn't been initialized, so `dealFormMapReads` is read as `null`, which eventually causes the NPE.

Lazily loading will fix it:

```
implicit val dealFormMapReads: Reads[DealFormMap] = (
     (JsPath \ "limit").readNullable[Int] and
     (JsPath \ "filter").lazyReadNullable[DealFormFilterMap](dealFormFilterMapReads)
)(DealFormMap)
```

Or you could just swap the order in which the `Reads` are defined.

---

The NPE thrown here is similar to this example:

```
case class A(i: Int)

object Test {
     val test = a.toString
     val a = A(1)
}

// Compiles up to here

Test.test // throws NPE, because `a` was not initialized before `test`
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the order as mentioned by LimbSoup. But it's worth noting that with using [Json macros](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonInception) you can  achieve the same result with

```
import play.api.libs.json._

implicit val dealFormFilterMapReads: Reads[DealFormFilterMap] = Json.reads[DealFormFilterMap]

implicit val dealFormMapReads: Reads[DealFormMap] = Json.reads[DealFormMap]
```

Note that by using this macros, if you change the order

```
implicit val dealFormMapReads: Reads[DealFormMap] = Json.reads[DealFormMap]

implicit val dealFormFilterMapReads: Reads[DealFormFilterMap] = Json.reads[DealFormFilterMap]
```

you will get the following helpful warning:

```
 Reference to uninitialized value dealFormFilterMapReads
[warn] implicit val dealFormMapReads: Reads[DealFormMap] = Json.reads[DealFormMap]
[warn]                                                                 ^
[warn] one warning found
```

which you can fix (again as mentioned by LimpSoup) by making `dealFormFilterMapReads` lazy or reordering which makes more sense in this case.

#### Disclaimer

Using Json macro inception in play needs Scala `2.10` and is supported on Play versions after `2.1.0`