# Turn off a "Forward reference" warning in a play framework recursive JSON reader

Tags: scala, playframework

On a play framework (Scala) web application, I parse some JSON getting a recursive type. To achieve this, I use a lazy reference of the reader, like is recommended on [play's official documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonCombinators) (scroll down to "recursive types").

This works, but I get a warning:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /path-to-project/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[warn] /path-to-project/app/controllers/JSONFormats.scala:116: Reference to uninitialized value layerTreeNodeFormat
[warn]   val folderNodeFormat = Format(folderNodeReads, Json.writes[FolderNode])
[warn]                                                             ^
[warn] one warning found
```

Is there any way I can turn this warning off?  I've looked at Scala's [`@unchecked`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.unchecked), but I'm not sure how (if at all) it could be applied here.

Thanks!

---

Edit: Below are the relevant parts of the code. The JSON parser parses a heterogeneous tree of map layers. Some nodes ("layers") are leafs, while other nodes ("folders") can contain layers and other folders (hence the recursion). On the Scala side, there's an abstract base class, `LayerTreeNode`, and two concrete case classes: `LayerNode` and `FolderNode`.

```
object ProjectJSONFormats {

  // omitted code...

  /** Turns the tuple parsed from JSON into a FolderNode. */
  def tupleToFolder( id:String, jsType:String, name:String, children:Seq[LayerTreeNode] ) = FolderNode(id, name, children)

  val folderNodeReads: Reads[FolderNode] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "type").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "title").readNullable[String].map( _.getOrElse("") ) and
      (JsPath \ "children").lazyReadNullable(Reads.seq[LayerTreeNode](layerTreeNodeReads)).map( _.getOrElse(Seq[LayerTreeNode]()))
    )( tupleToFolder _)

  val folderNodeFormat = Format(folderNodeReads, Json.writes[FolderNode])

  implicit val layerNodeFormat = Json.format[LayerNode]

  val layerTreeNodeReads: Reads[LayerTreeNode] = new Reads[LayerTreeNode] {
    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[LayerTreeNode] = {
      if ( (json\"type").as[String] == "folder" ) {
        folderNodeFormat.reads(json)
      } else {
        layerNodeFormat.reads(json)
      }
    }
  }
  val layerTreeNodeWrites: Writes[LayerTreeNode] = new Writes[LayerTreeNode] {
    override def writes(o: LayerTreeNode): JsValue = o match {
      case f:FolderNode => folderNodeFormat.writes(f)
      case l:LayerNode  => layerNodeFormat.writes(l)
    }
  }
  implicit val layerTreeNodeFormat:Format[LayerTreeNode] = Format( layerTreeNodeReads, layerTreeNodeWrites )

}
```

Comment: `@unchecked` doesn't apply here, as it is for ignoring type-checker warnings. Are you sure there isn't any merit to that warning? Initialization order could end up biting you here, but it's hard to say without seeing the actual code.

Comment: Thanks. As I said - it's idiomatic. It won't bite me back since I pass it as a parameter to a call-by-name method, JsPath#lazyReadNullable. (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsPath)

Comment: Could you add the actual code to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is completely justified by the compiler, so don't try to ignore it. You didn't share your case class structure, so I have to make some guesses, but the problem will present itself anyway. The `Reads` may be safe, but the `Writes` are not.

```
sealed abstract class LayerTreeNode(id: String, name: String)
case class FolderNode(id: String, name: String, children: Seq[LayerTreeNode]) extends LayerTreeNode(id, name)
case class LayerNode(id: String, name: String) extends LayerTreeNode(id, name)

val folder = FolderNode("ABC", "Parent", Seq(LayerNode("DEF", "Child")))

import ProjectJSONFormats._

scala> Json.toJson(folder)
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at play.api.libs.json.Json$.toJson(Json.scala:108)
  at play.api.libs.json.DefaultWrites$$anon$3$$anonfun$writes$2.apply(Writes.sc
  ... 43 elided
```

What happened? As the compiler warned us, `Json.writes[FolderNode]` requires an implicit `Writes[LayerNode]` or `Format[LayerNode]`. But `layerNodeFormat` is defined *after* the `Json.writes[FolderNode]` call, which means we can see it, but it is uninitialized. Now the `writes` method of `folderNodeFormat` has an NPE just waiting to present itself at the worst moment.

The fix is easy, simply make your `Writes` lazy as well. ie.:

```
lazy val folderNodeFormat = Format(folderNodeReads, Json.writes[FolderNode])

lazy val layerTreeNodeWrites: Writes[LayerTreeNode] = ...
```

And it works:

```
scala> Json.toJson(folder)
res10: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"id":"ABC","name":"Parent","children":[{"id":"DEF","name":"Child"}]}
```

The general problem is initialization order, and it will *definitely* bite you if you don't pay close attention. I've written more about it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26591397/2292812). The same applies to both `Reads` and `Writes`.

---

On a side note, using `(json \ "type").as[String] == "folder")` is also unsafe. If `"type"` is not actually a `String`, this will throw an exception.

```
val js = Json.parse("""{
  "id": "ABC",
  "name": "parent",
  "type": 1,
  "children": [
    {"id": "DEF", "name": "child", "type": "leaf"}
  ]
}""")

scala> js.validate[LayerTreeNode]
play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(error.expected.jsstring,WrappedArray())))))
  ... 43 elided // We probably don't want this to happen!
```

It would be better to use `validate` and `flatMap`:

```
  val layerTreeNodeReads: Reads[LayerTreeNode] = new Reads[LayerTreeNode] {
    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[LayerTreeNode] = {
      (json \ "type").validate[String] flatMap {
        case "folder" => folderNodeFormat.reads(json)
        case _ => layerNodeFormat.reads(json)
      }
    }
  }
```

Now the worst thing that can happen if we `validate[LayerTreeNode]` is that we get a `JsError` instead of throwing an exception.

```
scala> js.validate[LayerTreeNode]
res18: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[LayerTreeNode] = JsError(List((,List(ValidationError(error.expected.jsstring,WrappedArray())))))
```